# What is the set of languages accepted by empty stack pda?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

I am having a confusion. Empty stack pda will always accept episilon. Therefore a language not accepting episilon will still be accept episilon, so how can we avoid this?

Comment: "A language not accepting **epsilon** will still be accept epsilon". What is that supposed to mean? It is much clearer to say "empty word" or "empty string" instead of "epsilon", although we often use ϵ to denote it. A language is a set of words. It does not accept anything. It contains words. It might contain the empty word. A PDA accepts or rejects words. Please clarify your intention in the question. **The more detail, the better**.

Answer (score 4):

When defining the semantics of PDAs accepting with an empty stack, we initialize the stack with a special "bottom-of-stack" symbol. This solves your difficulty.

The set of languages accepted by empty-stack PDAs is the context-free languages. It is exactly the same set of languages accepted by final-state PDAs. The picture changes when considering deterministic PDAs: final-state DPDA accept the deterministic context-free languages, whereas empty-stack DPDAs accept the prefix-free deterministic context-free languages.